# Ramsey Interferometry in Three-Level Anharmonic System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interferometry

Recently I've been studying the pulse-level control experiments available in Qiskit like the [$T_2$ Ramsey experiments](https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/t2ramsey_characterization.html). I came across [this page](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/accessing_higher_energy_states.html#Build-the-0,-1,-2-discriminator-) and was surprised to find that there are three- and even four- or more level quantum systems available to play with in Qiskit. I started to think about what a Ramsey experiment with a three-level system would look like. Since most three-or-more-level systems are anharmonic, it seems to me that the way a Ramsey experiment would go would look something like this:

We prepare the qubit in $|0\rangle$ and apply the first Ramsey pulse with detuning of $\Delta_0$ with respect to the $|0\rangle\rightarrow|1\rangle$ transition and delay time $\tau$. This prepares the state:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle=\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}|0\rangle+\sin{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}|1\rangle\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Or something closely analogous to that. Now what if we apply a second pulse to this system with detuning $\Delta_1$ with respect to the $|1\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ transition, detuning $\Delta_2$ with respect to the $|0\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ transition, and detuning $\Delta_3$ with respect to the $|0\rangle\rightarrow|1\rangle$ transition and delay time $T$? My instinct (basically because its the simplest answer imaginable) says that the state after the second pulse should be something like:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle_f=\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\cos{\frac{\Delta_2{T}}{2}}\cos{\frac{\Delta_3T}{2}}|0\rangle+(\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_3T}{2}}+\sin{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\cos{\frac{\Delta_1T}{2}})|1\rangle+(\sin{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_1T}{2}}+\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_2T}{2}})|2\rangle\tag{2}
\end{equation}

To explain my reasoning, I think the state after the second pulse should have an amplitude for $|0\rangle$ which is the product of the amplitude that the system remained in $|0\rangle$ after the first pulse -- this is the $\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}$ term -- the amplitude it stayed in state $|0\rangle$ rather than making the $|0\rangle\rightarrow|1\rangle$ transition due to the second pulse -- this is the $\cos{\frac{\Delta_3T}{2}}$ term -- and the amplitude that it stayed in state $|0\rangle$ as opposed to making the $|0\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ transition due to the second pulse -- this is the $\cos{\frac{\Delta_2T}{2}}$ term.

The amplitude for $|1\rangle$ after the second pulse ought to be something like the superposition of the amplitudes that the system was in state $|1\rangle$ after the first pulse and stayed there after the second pulse -- this is the $(\sin{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\cos{\frac{\Delta_1T}{2}})$ term -- with the amplitude that it was in state $|0\rangle$ after the first pulse and made the transition $|0\rangle\rightarrow|1\rangle$ due to the second pulse -- this is the $(\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_3T}{2}})$ term.

Finally, the total amplitude for state $|2\rangle$ after the second pulse ought to be the superposition of the amplitudes that the system was in state $|0\rangle$ after the first pulse and made the transition $|0\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ due to the second pulse -- this is the $(\cos{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_2T}{2}})$ term -- with the amplitude that the system was in state $|1\rangle$ after the first pulse and made the transition $|1\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ due to the second pulse -- this is the $(\sin{\frac{\Delta_0\tau}{2}}\sin{\frac{\Delta_1T}{2}})$ term.

As I said, this is simply my first instinct as to how this system should work, but I have a suspicion that there might be more subtlety to it than this. I would appreciate if anyone is willing to tell me if this is correct or if there is a way of modifying it/how to model the system properly.